# Animating a circular progress circle smoothly via buttons

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cabasicanimation

I am experiencing odd visual quirks with my progress circle. I would like the green circle (CAShapeLayer) to smoothly animate in increments of fifths. 0/5 = no green circle. 5/5 = full green circle. The problem is the green circle is animating past where it should be, then abruptly shrinks back to the proper spot. This happens when both the plus and minus button are pressed. There is a gif below demonstrating what is happening.

The duration of each animation should last 0.25 seconds, and should *smoothly* animate both UP and DOWN (depending if the plus or minus button is pressed) from wherever the animation ended last (which is currently not happening.)

In my UIView, I draw the circle, along with the method to animate the position of the progress:

```
class CircleView: UIView {

    let progressCircle = CAShapeLayer()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.bounds)
        progressCircle.path = circlePath.cgPath
        progressCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        progressCircle.lineWidth = 10.0

        // Add the circle to the view.
        self.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle)
    }


    func animateCircle(circleToValue: CGFloat) {
        let fifths:CGFloat = circleToValue / 5
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.duration = 0.25
        animation.fromValue = fifths
        animation.byValue = fifths
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        progressCircle.strokeEnd = fifths

        // Create the animation.
        progressCircle.add(animation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
    }


}
```

In my VC:

I init the circle and starting point with:

```
let myDrawnCircle = CircleView()
var startingPointForCircle = CGFloat()
```

viewDidAppear:

```
    startingPointForCircle = 0.0
    myDrawnCircle.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 150, height: 150)
    myDrawnCircle.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    myDrawnCircle.animateCircle(circleToValue: startingPointForCircle)
    self.view.addSubview(myDrawnCircle)

    textLabel.text = "\(startingPointForCircle)"
```

And the actual buttons that do the cool animating:

```
@IBAction func minusButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if startingPointForCircle > 0 {
        startingPointForCircle -= 1
        textLabel.text = "\(startingPointForCircle)"
        myDrawnCircle.animateCircle(circleToValue: startingPointForCircle)
    }
}
@IBAction func plusButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if startingPointForCircle < 5 {
        startingPointForCircle += 1
        textLabel.text = "\(startingPointForCircle)"
        myDrawnCircle.animateCircle(circleToValue: startingPointForCircle)
    }
}
```

Here's a gif showing you what's going on with the jerky animations.

[image: Crude / jerky animation]

**How do I make my animations smoothly animate TO the proper value FROM the proper value?**

Comment: ... sorry I mis-read, so some details in my previous comment is off. Rather, I ment: shouldn't you be setting `animation.toValue` to fifths, and let `animation.fromValue` be `nil`, rather than the other way around? If you only set `animation.fromValue` to non-`nil`, then the animation will interpolate between `fromValue` and the current presentation value of the property, which is the previous value, but possibly in "the wrong direction" (e.g. drawing 2/5 clockwise to 1/5, rather than 1/5 clockwise to 2/5).

Comment: Commenting out both fromValue and toValue produced the exact results I was looking for... The question is though... Why? I can't understand how I'm getting the proper results without setting From / To. Is it because the strokeEnd property?

Comment: See the _Setting Interpolation Values_ section of the [`CABasicAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cabasicanimation) reference, and compare the different cases to the one you've specified above. If you **1)** set only `fromValue`, then interpolation will be from `fromValue` to current presentation value of the property (not what you want), **2)** set both `fromValue` and `toValue` to `nil` then: "Interpolates between the previous value of keyPath in the target layer’s presentation layer and the current value of keyPath in the target layer’s presentation layer.", OK.

Comment: A ha! Makes sense now :) Thanks for the help, @dfri

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired results were as simple as commenting out fromValue / byValue in the animateCircle method. This was pointed out by @dfri - "set both fromValue and toValue to nil then: "Interpolates between the previous value of keyPath in the target layer’s presentation layer and the current value of keyPath in the target layer’s presentation layer."

```
//animation.fromValue = fifths
//animation.byValue = fifths
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it has something to do with using a key path. I don't know how exactly to fix it for using a key path, but you could try a different tack, using a custom view, and animating the value passed to the method used for drawing an arc.

The code below was generated by PaintCode. The value passed for `arc` specifies the point on the circle to draw the arc to. This is used in the `drawRect` method of a custom UIView. Make a CGFloat property of the custom view and simply change that value, and call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view after your animation code.

```
func drawCircleProgress(frame frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40), arc: CGFloat = 270) {
    //// General Declarations
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //// Color Declarations
    let white = UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 1.000, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.000)
    let white50 = white.colorWithAlpha(0.5)

    //// Oval Drawing
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, frame.minX + 20, frame.minY + 20)
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, -90 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180)

    let ovalRect = CGRect(x: -19.5, y: -19.5, width: 39, height: 39)
    let ovalPath = UIBezierPath()
    ovalPath.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: ovalRect.midX, y: ovalRect.midY), radius: ovalRect.width / 2, startAngle: 0 * CGFloat(M_PI)/180, endAngle: -arc * CGFloat(M_PI)/180, clockwise: true)

    white.setStroke()
    ovalPath.lineWidth = 1
    ovalPath.stroke()

    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bud, but I got it working with my current setup. Alas, you've got me 'PaintCode' intrigued.. :)

Comment: @joe np, glad you got it working. Paintcode is an awesome tool!